# Question about register page architecture design

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a registration page in react native.

I want to create a registration page where you write your email first, then if valid, goes to another page where it validate your name instead of trying to make users add all the information in one page.

I am wondering if its better to create a component for every single page, (input email, input passsword, input username etc..) 
or if its better to do it in one component using states.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is if you make different components for each page, firstly it would not be the best approach, but on the other hand, it would be difficult for you to maintain those different pages in terms of both styling and logic.

It would be better to use the same component and manage states for the page.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is using state.
In your case, using one component for each input seems to be too much.